# Multi-row card visual with two selected values without table relationships

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I want to display a multi-row card visual in Power BI.
This card visual should represent the report date and the reference date selected by the user beforehand.
For this purpose, there are two tables, which are identical, namely `tableReport` and `tableReference`. These two tables must not be related to each other due to many specific calculations and representations in the Power BI report.
Unfortunately, without a relationship between the two tables, I cannot display the previously selected reference date in the visual.

[image]

**How can this be circumvented? Is it even possible to display two selected values in one visual under the condition that the two values do not have a table relationship?**

Comment: Write a measure using `LOOKUPVALUE`. This works without relationship between tables.

Comment: Something like ``refDate = LOOKUPVALUE(SELECTEDVALUE(tableReference[columnDate]))``? The error is then: "Too few arguments passed - the function requires 3 arguments."

Answer (score 0):

```
Measure1 = SELECTEDVALUE(tableReport[columnDate]))

Measure2 = SELECTEDVALUE(tableReference[columnDate]))
```

Pull these two measures into Multirow card fields

Comment: When I try this, then I only can display one of these measures. Putting ``measure2`` to the card-visual yields an empty ``measure1``, which should describe reportDate. How can I display two measures, when the measures are in different tables and the tables doesn't have a relationship?